# Matlab - How to compare data in two arrays and output largest

Tags: arrays, matlab, max

I have a 60,000-by-2 array. The first column is data 1 and second column is data 2; both of equal length. I'm not sure how to properly write the syntax to compare data 1 to data 2, and if data 1 is larger than data 2 then write that to the third column. Or vice versa if data 2 is larger than data 1. I have begun constructing a `for` loop, but I'm having syntax issues comparing the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No loops are needed. If you simply want to create a vector containing the largest element in each row of your 60,000-by-2 matrix you can use the [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function:

```
A = rand(6e4,2); % Random demo data

B = max(A,[],2);
```

Or if you then want to put the result directly in a third column of `A`:

```
A(:,3) = max(A,[],2);
```

Read the documentation for `max`. You'll see that the `2` in the third argument applied the max function across each row of the input, `A`.